# What is the list of comics series about Thanos (Marvel Comics) and the Infinity Gauntlet?

Tags: marvel, infinity-stones, thanos

I just remembered about my childhood comics and remembered The Infinity series involving Thanos in the 90's. After a quick search I found out that the series continued well after I stopped collecting comics.

What I found so far:

1. The Thanos Quest (1990)
2. The Infinity Gauntlet (1991)
3. The Infinity War (1992)
4. The Infinity Crusade (1993)
5. Thanos - Infinity Abyss (2002)
6. Marvel Universe - The-End (2003)

Is this the complete storyline? Am I missing something about Thanos and it's Infinity crossover?

Comment: You did miss some a few, check out the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thanos#Collected_editions) and it should fill you in nicely.

Comment: As Samalot points out below, Infinity Crusade does not feature the Infinity Gauntlet or any of the Infinity Gems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanos Quest laid the groundwork for Infinity Gauntlet which was supposed to be the crossover of all crossovers for the Marvel Universe (even bigger than the Secret War). It was such a massive success that they decided to turn it into a trilogy of crossover events, Infinity Gauntlet, Infinity War and Infinity Crusade. After the end of Infinity Crusade, the Infinity Gauntlet continued to be a part of the Marvel Universe (Adam Warlock created a team called The Infinity Watch specifically for the purpose of safeguarding it), but that was the official "end" of the Gauntlet centric big-huge crossover stuff until 2002 when Marvel decided to retread the idea.

Answer (score -1):

Thanos Quest was where he first got the gems, it set up Infinity Gauntlet. Then, that got a sequel, Infinity War. Both of which centrally had the infinity gems and Warlock and Thanos, but Infinity Gauntlet was the only one with Thanos as the villain. They had a sequel, Infinity Crusade, which did not feature the gems but rather some stolen cosmic cubes ( due to The living tribunal ruling against the gems working in unison ). I think the last three are set a while after, but do feature Thanos and the gems.