# What, if anything, do comics suggest about what happens to Loki in Infinity War?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, comics, avengers-infinity-war

I suspect that Loki is:

> not dead.

It seems unlikely for Loki to deceive Thanos poorly because Loki:

1. likely knows Thanos wouldn't fall for the deception right away or at all
2. likely sufficiently understands the power of the stones

   > 3. has faked death before.

It seems far more likely that Loki deceives Thanos:

> fakes death again

and doesn't tell Thor about it in advance (but does so through [veiled message/s](https://www.reddit.com/r/FanTheories/comments/8h2tyh/about_that_loki_scene_mcu_fan_theory_infinity_war/)) because otherwise Thor would give it away.

As for the comics, I tried checking wiki, but there seems to be nothing. 'Thanos' name is not in [Loki's wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loki_(comics)). Loki is mentioned only once in [Thanos' Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thanos).

Instead of reinventing the wheel by going through summaries or any of these [What is the list of comics series about Thanos (Marvel Comics) and the Infinity Gauntlet?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/58774), I thought I'd ask those who already know. If there is indeed some part of comics that may have a suggestion, please mention where I could find such in non-spoilers and then you can answer, if you want, in spoiler.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you are trying to speculate that a certain character is "on a certain side of the fence" based on information from comics. IMO this will not really enlighten anything for you... given the differences between universes. The events between the two are vastly different as I understand them and if a character is one way in the comics does not necessarily mean they will be the same in the films. In addition, given this character's past it is safe to assume that your instincts are correct... but we will of course not now until the next chapter is released...

Comment: @Odin1806 post as answer? Thanks, and happy 6th week of Easter! ^-^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR**

The two universes are separate so even if something happens in one, it may not happen in the other...

First off, there are differences between the comic book universe and the cinematic universe. I will not take the time to name them, given it should be rather obvious, but they are of course numerous as well.

Even if the situation you are searching for happened in the comics it would be no guarantee that it would cross over to the cinematic story line. This speculation may or may not prepare you to see something in the upcoming films that will or won't be there. Depending on the type of person you are this could completely ruin your expectations and thus ruin your experience...

That said:

> Loki is a scheming individual. He has appeared in three of Thor's movies and he has died in two of them... or so we thought. We also know from the first Avengers film that he can manipulate stuff while operating multiple projections (Trapping Thor and killing Colson). Given these details it is entirely possible that Loki survived and will make a triumphant return.

That said, despite Loki's personal motivations I like to think he would have gone with Thor to help defeat Thanos in some way given he also stayed after regaining the Tesseract at the end of Ragnarok and it seemed the two were back on the same, or at least parallel, wavelengths. I don't remember Thanos telling Thor his ultimate plan though so it is possible that Loki felt he had more to fear from him than "being destroyed with half the population of the galaxy" and hid to save his own skin...

However:

> I have heard that the Marvel universe was gearing up to hand over the reigns to new heroes (Ant-Man, Spider-Man, etc.) and that the current roster (Iron Man, Thor, etc.) all wanted to retire ([for example](http://www.joblo.com/movie-news/robert-downey-jr-will-officially-step-down-as-iron-man-after-infinity-war-144)). So given some actors desire an exit, it is possible that Tom did/does as well.

But check these out: [Link 1](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/2407821/tom-hiddleston-has-a-message-for-fans-worried-about-loki-in-avengers-infinity-war) and [Link 2](https://www.express.co.uk/entertainment/films/955179/Avengers-Infinity-War-Loki-dead-Tom-Hiddleston-twist-return-Avengers-4) ... so... maybe?